# Enumerate stops counting after returning a function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, enumeration

My problem is that I want to call the `return logout()` in my worker but that does break the enumerate and sets the `idx` counter on 0 so it won't print `item`. How can return logout without having this problem?

**code:**

```
import time

def logout():
    print("logout")

N = 4
def worker():
    for idx, Item in enumerate(range(1, 12)):
        if idx % N == 0:
            print("Done Session") 
            time.sleep(1)
            return logout()
        print(Item)    

worker()
worker()
worker()
```

**output:**

```
Done Session
logout
Done Session
logout
Done Session
logout
```

**expected output:**

```
Done Session
logout
1
2
3
4
Done Session
logout
5
6
7
8
Done Session
logout
...
```

Comment: @PETERSTACEY no because the print call is related to the if statement. calling it before the if would stop counting after 1x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the necessary things in a list, and then return them all at once *(note: I commented some lines of code that aren't necessary for the output)*:

```
N = 4
def worker():
    log = [] # Not needed
    for idx, Item in enumerate(range(1, 12)):
        if idx % N == 0:
            print("Done Session") 
            time.sleep(1)
            log.append(logout()) # logout()
        print(Item)
    return log # Not needed
```

Result:

```
Done Session
logout
1
2
3
4
Done Session
logout
5
6
7
8
Done Session
logout
9
10
11
Done Session
logout
1
2
3
4
Done Session
logout
5
6
7
8
Done Session
logout
9
10
11
Done Session
logout
1
2
3
4
Done Session
logout
5
6
7
8
Done Session
logout
9
10
11
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
N = 4
def worker():
    for idx, Item in enumerate(range(1, 12)):
        if idx % N == 0:
            print("Done Session") 
            time.sleep(1)
            logout()
        print(Item)
```